# Swap elements of variable names around

Tags: dplyr, stringr, data-wrangling

I have variable names that follow the same pattern...

Measure name, item number, collection wave all separated by underscore.

For example, `measure_1_baseline`.

I want to swap the last two parts around so that the pattern becomes...

Measure name, collection wave, item number, e.g. `measure_baseline_1`.

I am currently working with a vector of variable names (having accessed the relevant columns using the `names()` function).

Here is an example vector that would apply to my dataset...

```
var_names <- c("measure_1_baseline", "measure_2_baseline", "measure_3_baseline", "measure_1_followup", "measure_2_followup", "measure_3_followup")
```

Ideally, I would like this to work using tidyverse syntax so I can use it in a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.fn` argument of `dplyr::rename_with`.

First, an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "measure_1_baseline" = 0, 
  "measure_2_baseline" = 0, 
  "measure_3_baseline" = 0, 
  "measure_1_followup" = 0,
  "measure_2_followup" = 0, 
  "variable_3_followup" = 0
)

  measure_1_baseline measure_2_baseline measure_3_baseline measure_1_followup measure_2_followup variable_3_followup
1                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                   0
```

And a generalized solution:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = ~gsub('(measure|variable)_(\\d+)_(.*)', '\\1_\\3_\\2', .x), .cols = matches('^(measure|variable)'))

colnames(df2)

[1] "measure_baseline_1"  "measure_baseline_2"  "measure_baseline_3"  "measure_followup_1"  "measure_followup_2" 
[6] "variable_followup_3"
```

Comment: would there be a way to generalise the code even more so that the first part of the string 'measure_' can be used for multiple columns with different strings at the start? e.g. if the `.cols = starts_with(c('measure', 'variable'))` was expanded as so to feature additional variable names.

Comment: See edits! I use `matches('^(measure|variable)')`, which is equivalent to your `starts_with(c('measure', 'variable'))`