# Swap elements of a column name using gsub

Tags: dplyr, gsub, data-wrangling

In a previous post I was shown how to swap elements of a column name around for a specific instance...

[Swap elements of variable names around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195701/swap-elements-of-variable-names-around)

Is it possible to have a more general gsub function that swaps the text occurring after the second underscore with the text occurring after the third underscore?

I have multiple column names in a dataset that look something like 'measure_subscale_wave' and I would like them to be in the format 'measure_wave_subscale'.

I have something along these lines based on the post I referenced above.

```
data_test <- data %>% 

  rename_with(
    .fn = ~gsub(
      pattern = 'measure_???_(.*)', # Not sure what would go on this line 
      replacement = '\\1_\\3_\\2', 
      .x
    ), 
    .cols = matches('^measure')
  )
```

Comment: Try `pattern = '(measure)_(.*)_(.*)'` with `replacement = '\\1_\\3_\\2'`

Comment: Perfect. If you want to submit this as an answer I can accept it as the correct solution to give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
data_test <- data %>% 

  rename_with(
    .fn = ~gsub(
      pattern = '(measure)_(.*)_(.*)'
      replacement = '\\1_\\3_\\2',
      .x
    ), 
    .cols = matches('^measure')
  )
```

Here,

- `(measure)` - Group 1 (`\1`): a `measure` word
- `_` - an underscore
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `(.*)` - Group 3 (`\3`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible